# How do I get error bars to be same color as points/lines in matplotlib

Tags: python, graphics, matplotlib

Here is my code (with lots of lines removed)

columnArray is a 2D array of numbers.

Here is the code

---

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for i in range(0,numLines)

    columnArray = ....

    plt.plot(columnArray[0],columnArray[1], type, label=lineLabel)

    plt.errorbar(columnArray[0],columnArray[1],yerr=errColumnArray[1])

plt.legend(loc='best')
```

The problem is that I want the lines, markers and error bars for each line to be the same colour. With this the color of the error bars and lines differs and the line is not shown in the correct color on the legend.

Answer (score 4):

Removing the ´plot´ command, since ´errorbar´ already does the plotting, will give you a single color per plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for i in range(numLines):

    columnArray = ....

    plt.errorbar(columnArray[0],columnArray[1],yerr=errColumnArray[1], label=lineLabel)

    plt.legend(loc='best')
```

Comment: Both `plot` and `errorbar` have several color-related kwargs.